# Django specific permissions for users

Tags: python, django

for example i have a model with booleanfield

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pending = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

if user creates new item from admin panel pending field is false and this item won't display on website until other user  set this field into True, but this user mustn't be allowed to make change on pending field on his items but he can do this activity on other users items. any solutions?

Comment: please fix your indentation

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to implement this, depending on how you are ultimately going to end up using it. The most straightforward is to add a foreignkey on your Item to the user (assuming you use django auth).

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Item(BaseModels):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pending = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

assuming this only ever gets exposed via views, then you can just do:

```
def some_view(request):
    if item_being_edited.created_by = request.user and not item_being_edited.pending:
         #rejection goes here
    #do stuff
```

as a sidenote, change your pending field. Either have pending = True mean an item is pending, or have it to be approved = False. It will make things easier later if it makes sense to read it in your head without gymnastics.

Comment: is there any possible ways that user who created this item won't be allowed to change this field value from admin panel?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. If you need security from admin users you're likely going to need a new authorisation model

Comment: i don't think there is a necessity for a new authorisation model. i need that this one field in admin panel this boolean field(pending) must be changable for other users not by request.user who created this object

Comment: @I.Jokhadze the django.contrib.auth functionality doesn't support that level of row level permissions control. The plugin http://django-authority.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ claims to do so, but I haven't looked at in any detail.

Comment: Ty for help. I'll try this one